# Return the result value with fetch call function from another page, React native

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await, fetch-api

I need to return the result of a function from another page in react native which performing a fetch call. I use the method as follows. As I know this is because asynchronous call. Is there a special way to achieve this in react native ?

**fetchcall.js**

```
import address from '../actions/address'
const dashboard = {
  getvals(){

    return fetch(address.dashboardStats(),
    {method: "POST",
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify( {...
      }),
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
      console.warn(responseData);
      return responseData;

    })
    .catch((error) => { console.warn(error); })
    .done();
    // return 'test_val'';
  }
}

export default dashboard;
```

**dashboard.js**

```
import dashboard from '../../services/dashboard';
class Dashboard extends Component {


  componentDidMount(){
      console.warn(dashboard.getvals());
  }

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, bindAction)(Dashboard);
```

Its display the result as "undefined", but that fetch call works and it displays the result. Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you sure it is `getTestval` and not `getvals`?

Comment: @akond, Sorry for that, It was a mistake when editing the question. I edited it now.

Comment: I see that you are using react-redux connect, but i dont see mapStateToProps definition at all. Are you even using it at all? Would you consider a solution without redux?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

In **fetchcall.js** you are returning a Promise. Also since you are returning the `responseData` in the `.then()` method itself, you don't need the `.done()` method.

Since `getvals()` is returning a Promise, you need to access it's value in a `.then()` method.

Overall, your code should be like this:

```js
  function getvals(){
    return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    {
     method: "GET",
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
      console.log(responseData);
      return responseData;
    })
    .catch(error => console.warn(error));
  }
  
  getvals().then(response => console.log(response));
```

Comment: Sorry, I know this is old now but why the `console.warn()` before returning `responseData`. Is there something wrong with returning that or is it supposed to be a `console.log()`?

Comment: It should be `console.log()`. I'll change it.

Comment: Pls tell me how to pass and i want to export

function getvals(){
    return fetch('http://xxx'')
   .then((response) => response.json())
   .then((json) => {
     return json.products;
   })
   .catch((error) => {
     console.error(error);
   });
  }
  
  getvals().then(response => response);


const ProductsList =getvals().then(response => response);

export default ProductsList;

Comment: the `return fetch` is ok but the other `return responseData` statement inside `then` is wrong and won't work!

Answer (score 8):

The best architectural pattern, I think, is to use a callback function, usually by writing in as an anonymous function.

```
///Component.js
my_service.login((data=>{
  this.setState({body: data.body});
}));

////Service.js
export  const login = function (cb){
  fetch('http://myapi.com/103?_format=hal_json')
    .then((response) =>{
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) =>{
      cb(data);
    });
}
```

I am still a junior developer, but use this pattern frequently. If someone has a reason for a different approach, I would love to hear it.

Comment: how to get using your function not just `data` but  also `response`?

Answer (score 2):

fetch always return a Promise doesn't matter what you are returning.
so you can return a string, variable or something else but you have to use **.then** to access data

**file where you make fetch request**

```
export const graphql = () => {
  return fetch("https://graphqlzero.almansi.me/api", {
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": { "content-type": "application/json" },
    "body": JSON.stringify({
      query: `{
      user(id: 1) {
        id
        name
      }
    }`
    })
  })
    .then((res) => res.json()).then((responseData) => {
      console.log(responseData);
      return responseData;
    })


}
```

**file where you call function**

```
 graphql()
 .then((e) => {
     console.log("data", e)
  });
```