# Access array from API outside of fetch

Tags: javascript

I cannot figure out how to get data from a fetch response into a new global variable. I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44644138/return-the-result-value-with-fetch-call-function-from-another-page-react-native) question but I don't want to `console.log()` the array, but instead put it into a new variable.

Using the linked question, I am doing almost the same:

```
function getvals(){
  return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseData) => {
    return responseData;
  })
}

let data;
getvals().then(response => {
  data=response;
})
```

I would like the `data` variable to hold the array that is return. I thought I would just have to declare a new global variable and then change within the `.then` but I get undefined.

Comment: I just ran your code and can access `data` globally, where are you trying to access it from? maybe there's another `data` variable somewhere, in the arguments or something?

Comment: When are you checking to see if `data` is set? `getvals()` returns a promise, and code execution does not wait for the `.then()` to execute. If you're trying to get the value of the variable directly after the `getvals()` call, it will be undefined because the `fetch` request hasn't finished yet. You need to either await it or use a callback within the `then()`

Comment: @Jesse where would I place the await? Sorry, fairly new to JS

Comment: @Yolo_chicken if you want to use await use this code `async function getvals() {
  const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
  const responseData = await response.json();
  return responseData;
}` but I don't think is necessary, if you want here the code refactored

Answer (score 1):

Run your code in an *async function*.
Because of the nature of Promises you can't break the promises outside of an asynchronous flow. Learn more about [Using Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) and the [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) syntax to become familiar with the concepts. They're a  game changer.

```
function getvals(){
  return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    .then((response) => response.json());
}

async function main() {
  const data = await getvals(); // Waits here until getvals() is done.
  console.log(data);
}

main();
```

Comment: I'm getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules`. I tried adding `async` in front of `function getVals(){}` but same error.

Comment: Ah yes, I've misread that top-level `await` only works in modules.

Comment: Instead of outputting `data` in `console.log`, I would like it set as a global variable. I've tried `let data;` above `main()` and removing `const`, but no luck. Still getting `undefined`?

Comment: I know you would like that, but that's not how Promises work. You have to *wait* before `getvals()` continues, and the only way to do that is **inside** the scope of an *async function* or in the callback function of the promises's `then` method.